# HP Smart Array P420i Configuration - LZMA data is corrupt

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to get into the Array Configuration Utility for the Smart Array P420i controller. The server is a HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8.

After POST, I press F5 as asked in order to get to the ACU. However, during boot of the ACU, it presents me the following error:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: LZMA data is corrupt
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 3.0.76-0.11-default #1
Call Trace:
[...]
```

Could anyone tell me what to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

The error you have is about the Linux kernel not booting due to corrupted initramfs. It has nothing to do with the RAID controller configuration utility

Answer (score 0):

the screen you posted is related to your OS.it has nothing todo with the RAID controller. After having the server started with the power button, keep pressing F10 for intelligent provisioning menu and after that select Perform maintenance, there you can access to RAID controller configuration.